# cerrar Jframe sin cerrar todas las ventanas

Tags: java

Tengo mas de un JFrame, abro el primero, y de ahi abro el segundo, por ejemplo, pero cuando cierro el segundo, tambien me cierra el primero, y quiero que quede abierto, por ahora tengo este codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que use para que "no se cierre" pero no funciona.
Queria saber si alguien tiene alguna otra manera de hacerlo.
Gracias!!:)

Comment: Hola @Melannie, te propongo que intentes dejar tu frame principal con la constante 'EXIT_ON_CLOSE' y a las demás ventanas (secundarias) ponles la constante 'DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE', cuando cierres cada una hazlo con dispose(). Creo a ciencia cierta que te funcionará.

Comment: SI, tenias razon! Me funciono muy bien!! Muchas gracias :) @Johnny